# Count number of logins between hours

Tags: sql, business-objects

I'm sure this has been answered before but I'll ask anyway.

I have been asked to produce a report of account logins throughout the day and count how many accounts logged in over the span of hours. For example 3 logins between 7-8am, 7 logins between 8-9am, 2 logins between 9-10am and so on. I need to count the number for each account between each hour slot. IE, do not aggregate all the data.

I currently just count the number of times an account has logged in over the last 30 days but management would like to see a more detailed split of the data.

I am using the sap business objects audit Universe.

Is there a quick way to do this?

EDIT: I have added some sample data to help answer the question. User X is a generic user, but where the dates and times are different, this signifies a different user account.

```
(No column name)    Start_Time
User X  2021-10-26 13:10:50.503
User X  2021-10-27 07:15:11.217
User X  2021-10-27 10:02:00.440
User X  2021-10-29 07:50:14.280
User X  2021-10-29 09:05:56.410
User X  2021-10-29 10:03:45.117
User X  2021-10-29 15:12:41.167
User X  2021-10-13 08:05:27.193
User X  2021-10-14 10:02:30.320
User X  2021-10-14 11:06:19.340
User X  2021-10-14 11:53:53.280
User X  2021-10-14 14:44:56.773
User X  2021-10-15 07:44:13.780
User X  2021-10-15 12:25:05.773
User X  2021-10-07 08:02:49.997
User X  2021-10-16 08:56:15.673
User X  2021-10-15 08:52:40.560
User X  2021-10-15 08:54:00.637
User X  2021-10-15 15:37:26.960
User X  2021-10-19 11:34:08.003
User X  2021-10-19 15:22:07.290
User X  2021-10-09 13:07:09.480
User X  2021-10-09 13:41:31.073
User X  2021-10-29 11:50:10.287
User X  2021-10-29 12:08:54.543
User X  2021-10-29 12:38:58.620
User X  2021-10-30 10:48:19.987
User X  2021-10-30 14:53:59.653
User X  2021-10-26 13:49:31.597
User X  2021-10-20 07:17:22.093
User X  2021-10-21 10:12:09.660
User X  2021-10-23 11:44:14.200
User X  2021-10-25 11:04:24.607
User X  2021-10-13 07:41:03.000
User X  2021-10-18 07:23:59.150
User X  2021-10-18 08:48:31.407
User X  2021-10-08 07:35:43.460
User X  2021-10-08 07:36:38.147
User X  2021-10-22 12:26:59.753
User X  2021-10-22 12:43:59.010
User X  2021-10-20 09:39:02.800
User X  2021-10-20 09:15:58.913
User X  2021-10-28 12:51:15.637
User X  2021-10-28 13:20:40.020
User X  2021-10-08 10:40:11.550
User X  2021-10-08 11:16:16.170
User X  2021-10-04 07:48:15.457
User X  2021-10-04 09:01:08.407
User X  2021-10-15 12:17:10.337
User X  2021-10-15 11:47:10.150
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't really expect any suggestions without showing us some sample data.

Comment: Have added some sample data to help answer the question Tim.

Comment: So I have figured out how to do this in SQL and appears to work. But I get a MULTIVALUE error when creating/building the report in Business objects. Any idea on how to get the formulas to work correctly to show the same on the report?

Comment: Please provide an example of your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use variables to break the **Start_Time** into as fine of grained components you want to group your login counts. I created three; **Date**, **Hour**, and **AM or PM** defined as follows (the formula is only the equals sign and everything to the right of it)...

```
Date=ToDate(FormatDate([Start_Time]; "ddMMyyyy"); "ddMMyyyy")

Hour=FormatDate([Start_Time]; "hh")

AM or PM=FormatDate([Start_Time]; "a")
```

Now we need a variable to count the users. By default, the Count() function only counts distinct values occurring in the given context.

```
Login Count Distinct=Count([User])
```

So I created another variable to count all values in the given context.

```
Login Count All=Count([User]; All)
```

Put it all together and there you have it. You will notice the Login Counts are the same except for the 7:00 PM hour where one user had three logins accounting for that difference.

[image]

Does that meet your requirement?

Noel

Comment: Yes this did the trick. thanks!